# Finding real part of an exponential with more than 1 term in the exponent.

Tags: complex-numbers

z = $ \ sqrt2 \ + isqrt{2}  \ w = \frac{pi}{4} + 2i $. Find Re{Ze^(iw)}. Now, i have simplified the exponential form to $\ 2 \ e^{( \frac{pi*i}{2} \ - 2)} $. But not quite sure how to derive the real part of this equation as I am not able to apply euler's formula in this case.

Comment: What is rad here?

Comment: to the power of 1/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $1+i=\sqrt2(\cos\pi/4+i\sin\pi/4)=\sqrt2e^{i\pi/4}$

$$(\sqrt2+i\sqrt2)\cdot e^{i(\pi/4+2i)}$$

$$=e^{-2}\sqrt2(1+i)\cdot e^{i\pi/4}$$

$$=e^{-2}2\cdot e^{i\pi/4}\cdot e^{i\pi/4}$$

$$=2e^{-2}\cdot e^{i\pi/2}$$

$$=2e^{-2}i$$

Comment: sorry, there's a confusion. Let me edit my question.

Comment: there is an i, next to the pi. so it's i*pi/2 -2

Comment: @JonathanSmit, Yes. So, its $$e^{i\pi/2-2}=e^{-2}\cdot e^{i\pi/2}=\cdots$$

Comment: So there is no real part?

Comment: and i'm not sure where the 1+i comes from.

Comment: @JonathanSmit, Take out $\sqrt2$ as common factor in $z$

Comment: wait, sorry, I see what you were doing. ok ok. So given all this, there still isn't a real part for this equation? just an imaginary?

Comment: @JonathanSmit, What is wrong with that?